# Import Error: cannot import name MultiPartParser

Tags: python, django, lrs

I'm trying to deploy the ADL_LRS 0.90. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python
sudo apt-get install python-django
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install fabric
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools libmysqlclient-dev python-dev python-mysqldb python-libxml2 python-libxslt1 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
mysqladmin -h localhost -u root -p create lrs
```

Then I edited the file ADL_LRS/adl_lrs/settings.py with my USER and PASSWORD entries for my MySQL DB
Then I ran the command: `python manage.py createcachetable cache_statement_list` in the ADL_LRS directory
Then `python manage.py syncdb`
and finally `./manage.py runserver` and everything works fine
but when I try to access to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ I get the following error:

```
cannot import name MultiPartParser
```

This is the line:

```
from django.http import MultiPartParser
```

Someone knows what could be happening?

Comment: So, it looks like the name of the module is multipartparser and that contains a class MultiPartParser... did you try doing from django.http.multipartparser import MultiPartParser

Comment: @Foon I didn't see your comment until after I posted, but if you'd like you should answer that and I will delete mine.

Comment: no worries; hopefully that answers the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should stay with the requirements.txt they provide...
As both of our collegues describes about the version of django in ubuntu repository is bigger than the one used by ADL_RSL, and perhaps django update the code base.

I suggest you follow their how to install in their github page... in there, they use pip and virtualenv to keep the project consise.

https://github.com/adlnet/ADL_LRS

If then you want to update their software to a bigger django version, and correct the bugs (as the one you report there) i think they will appreciate.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/multipartparser.py) that should be:

```
from django.http.multipartparser import MultiPartParser
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 14.04, the python-django package is 1.6.1, and it looks like ADL_LRS requires Django==1.4.